# How to add element (script) to content

Tags: javascript, replace, window.location

I want to insert this in script in order to redirect the page

```
<div id="hello">

<div>You are going to be redirected!</div>

<p>http://www.google.com</p>
```

will become

```
<div id="hello">

<div>You are going to be redirected!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com"
</script>

</div>
```

I don't know how to replace `<p>` and `</p>`by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "
```

and

```
"
</script>
```

Comment: Just... type it? In your editor?

Comment: No, I need to add it with javascript because my page will dynamicaly display the content

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the meta tag for redirecting like this so you are not reliant on Javascript? Is there a specific need for it to be Javascript? [Look at the bottom example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that's all there is in your page in the way of content, try this:

```
location.href = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```